# import HTML to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I need to import A.html and B.html and C.html into Index.html

The way that I tried.....it can work,
but dont know way only one is normal,
other not link with their css

---

below is my index.html

it can work, but only D.html is link its css.
Others looks not right layout with their css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/A.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/B.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/C.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/D.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js" defer></script>
<section ng-app="">
  <div ng-include="'section/A.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'section/B.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'section/C.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'section/D.html'"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Show the code inside A, B, C and D

Comment: but too many.............

Comment: We can't help you with so little info, it's like showing us the window of a car and asking us what's wrong with the engine.

Comment: I found that always the one close to </section> can catch its own CSS, but others cannot –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a codepen project I did to help you with your issue:
https://codepen.io/ideaguy3d/project/editor/AdzPdm

I just added an angular app and pointed ng-app to it:

app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

index.html:

```

```
   <section ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-include="'section/A.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'B.html'"></div>

    </section>
```

```

Make sure there is a folder called "section" in your project as well.

Comment: many thanks. but how can A.html link to A.css and B.html link to B.css?

Comment: I found that always the one close to </section> can catch its own CSS, but others cannot

Comment: By class names and specificity. If you have styles.css have a style `a-include-section some-descendant {color: "red"}` then in A.html have `<section class = "a-include-section"><div class = "some-descendant"></div></section>` and remember to include `styles.css` in your head element. If there is other styles that have higher specificity then you may have to resort to using an id